# Java 10 and Renjin hangs Intellij

Tags: renjin

After upgrading to Java 9, then to Java 10, I noticed in both cases, after a couple hours of debugging, that it is the Renjin library that hangs Intellij, for example, when I try to run any program in the project.

What happens is that the IDE just says it's "Parsing" the project. Then, after about 1 - 3 minutes, Intellij crashes with a memory overflow error. Once I remove the rengin plug-in, all is good again. I tried 'upping' the compiler heapsize, but that just increases the amount of time it takes before the memory error happens...

I'm using the "renjin-script-engine-0.9.2615-jar-with-dependencies.jar" version of the JAR file.

Although I looked (could have missed it), I haven't yet found any explanation why the library won't work with JDK 10 (or 9).

Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there any indication where IntelliJ is getting stuck on, for example, which of Renjin's classes? What version of IDEA are using?

Comment: I didn't have time to trace it down to that level as I lost over a day trying to determine the basic problem so I could get back to work. Once I removed the renjin jar file after a long day of debugging this problem, Intellij was fine. Looking on the renjin site, yesterday (3/25/18), I thought I saw where they only officially support Java 8.